# JTextField getText() not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, textfield

I am having trouble implementing the getText() method. For some reason when I press enter on the text box the input is not being transferred into a string called playerOneName. I've tried to put in an action listener and other methods but I have had no success, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
//imports
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
    //constant variables to use
    private static JTextField textField;
    

    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public mainClass() {
        
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        //set background color to white
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            
        }
        
        
      }

    public static void initializeBoard() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // title of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Risk");
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        String playerOneName= textField.getText();
        JLabel Name = new JLabel("");
        Name.setText(playerOneName);
        frame.add(Name,BorderLayout.EAST);

        JLabel welcome = new JLabel("");
        welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 2 in the text box at the bottom");
        frame.add(welcome,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // make sure it closes correctly
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        //frame size in pixels
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;    
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
        
        // makes sure the frame is visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mainClass main = new mainClass();
        frame.add(main);
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't override  paintComponent to change the background color of the panel. Instead you just use: `main.setBackground( Color.WHITE );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want to get the playerOneName whenever you hit enter after having written it in the textField. The problem is that you are not adding a listener to the component, so nothing is happening in the code you provided

Here, you would be adding the listener (which would triggered after pressing enter, for instance) and just printing it. You can now take the value and use it.

...

```
  frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println(textField.getText());
            }
        });
```

...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you set the value of 'playerOneName' at

```java
Name.setText(playerOneName);
```

This is before your frame becomes visible for input. So you cannot expect changes to your JTextField to be automatically pushed to a code i.e Name.setText(playerOneName) that has already been executed in the past. There is no automatic binding of your text field to the playerOneName variable. This means that every time you update text in your JTextField there is nothing that tells playerOneName variable to change accordingly.

In your case you want this to happen on pressing "Enter". The way you do this is as follows:

1. Attach an event listener to your GUI Element i.e JTextField here
2. In the event listener you will update the variable in question

The simplest way to do this is to add an ActionListener which detects "Enter" being pressed and will update playerOneName. So simply inside your main method (at the very end) add the following code:

```java
textField.addActionListener((e) -> {
    Name.setText(textField.getText());
});
```

In reality you can add this code in your main method anywhere after textField and name variable have been initialized.

However, there are many other improvements that you can make. For example Java uses camel case notation for naming variables. One quick way of rewriting your code can be:

```java
public class MainClassX extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Risk");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel name = new JLabel("");
        JLabel welcome = new JLabel("");
        
        MainClassX main = new MainClassX();
        welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 2 in the text box at the bottom");
    
        frame.add(name, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(welcome, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(main);
        
        textField.addActionListener((e) -> {
            name.setText(textField.getText());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a `KeyListener` to your `textField`, because right now you get the text from the TextField when the JFrame is created. So you need to get the text from `textField` after the user even had a chance to enter the username.

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            name.setText(textField.getText());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: (1-). Don't use a KeyListener. The JTextField was designed to use an ActionListener to handle the Enter key.