# How do you obtain 2 inputs from a user in Jtextfield?

Tags: java, swing, input, jtextfield

I want the user to type a name for player one and press enter and then for the textfield to be blank again so that the user can type in a name for player 2. so far I can only get player one's name as input but not player two. For some reason my code isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
    //constant variables to use

    static String playerOneName;
    static String playerTwoName;
    static boolean playerOneNameSet;
    static boolean playerTwoNameSet;
    
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public mainClass() {
        
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        //set background color to white
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        
      }

    public static void initializeBoard() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // title of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Risk");

            JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
            frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            
            JLabel welcome = new JLabel("");
            welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 1 in the text box at the bottom");
            frame.add(welcome,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            
            //action listener listens for enter key
            textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    playerOneName= textField.getText();
                    System.out.println(playerOneName);
                    playerOneNameSet = true;
                    System.out.println(playerOneNameSet);
                }
            });
            if(playerOneNameSet == true) {
            JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(20);
            frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            
            JLabel welcome2 = new JLabel("");
            welcome2.setText("Please Enter name for Player 2 in the text box at the bottom");
            frame.add(welcome2,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            
            //action listener listens for enter key
            textField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    playerTwoName= textField2.getText();
                    System.out.println(playerTwoName);
                    playerTwoNameSet = true;
                    System.out.println(playerTwoNameSet);
                }
            });
            }
            
        
        
        // make sure it closes correctly
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        //frame size in pixels
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;    
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
        
        // makes sure the frame is visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mainClass main = new mainClass();
        frame.add(main);
        
        
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not two JTextFields, one for player 1's name and one for player 2's name?

Comment: Why do you have two usernames? Why have you not removed your paintComponent() method as suggested in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65970363/131872. Use a JOptionPane to prompt for each user name. Read the Swing tutorial on [Getting the Users Input From a Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one logical error in your code.

***If you want to use only **one** `JTextField` for two inputs*, you do not need to create
**two** `JTextField`.** Just handle the `ActionEvent` and update only that `JTextField`. Here is the code for that:

```
    textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            if (!playerOneNameSet)
            {
                playerOneName = textField.getText();
                textField.setText("");
                welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 2 in the text box at the 
                                 bottom");
                playerOneNameSet = true;
            }
            else
            {
                playerTwoName = textField.getText();
                textField.setText("");       
            }
         }
     });
```

The `if` part after that is not required. It will also eliminate the use of `playerTwoNameSet`.

***If you want to use **two** `JTextField`*, then you have to do it in the start properly without any logical flaw.**

**Logical Error in Detail:**

Let me try to show you the flow of your program.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // title of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Risk");

        .
        .
        .
        .

        
        //action listener listens for enter key
        textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                playerOneName= textField.getText();
                System.out.println(playerOneName);
                playerOneNameSet = true;
                System.out.println(playerOneNameSet);
            }
        });
```

***Your code is all good till here. After the above line, this happens***

```
        if(playerOneNameSet == true)    //It is never executed
```

The reason this happens because `playerOneNameSet` is a `static` variable and its *default value* is `false`. ***This line is only executed once. Once your GUI is created, the main() method will not be called again until you run it again.*** After that, the control passes to the one `JTextField` that was created, that too when any `ActionEvent` is generated. It will never go to the `if` line after that.

I hope I have helped you. Do comment for any further problems.